# Wildcards in Java question

Tags: java, wildcard

Given the following classes

```
class Creature {}
class Animal extends Creature {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
```

And the following lists

```
List<? super Animal> l1;
List<? extends Animal> l2;
```

Which of these commands will cause a compilation error?

```
1) l1.add(new Dog())
2) l1.add(null)
3) Object a = l1.get(0)
4) l2.add(new Dog())
5) Creature c = l2.get(0))
```

I think it's four, because `? extends Animal` isn't necessarily a supertype of `Dog`, but I'm not completely sure. An explanation would help a lot :)

Comment: This is very vell explained in Effective Java [1] and in this video

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/
[2] http://youtu.be/V1vQf4qyMXg?t=21m

Comment: Why don't you just try it in a program ? Don't you want to become a programmer ? So make programs. Regards, Stéphane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An image may help in understanding:

[image: class diagram]

Also, see section [4.5.1 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.5.1), specially §4.5.1.1

Comment: How do you include pictures in answer @ninjalj ?

Comment: @Snicolas: the editing interface has a button for uploading images.

Answer (score 5):

### Super and Extends

The line `List<? super Animal> l1;` means that the list `l1` can be **instantiated** to hold objects of a *super-type* of `Animal`. Example: `l1 = new LinkedList<Creature>();`

The line `List<? extends Animal> l2;` means that the list `l2` can be **instantiated** to hold objects of a *subtype* of `Animal`. Example: `l2 = new LinkedList<Dog>();`

### Answers

Assuming that the lists are constructed.

1) The list `l1` may be instantiated to hold any super-type of `Animal`. Since `Dog` is a subtype of any super-type of `Animal` it can be casted implicitely. Compiles.

2) Compiles always. The specification of `List` does not deny nulls. Runtime exception depends on the whether the list implementation allows null elements. LinkedList allows nulls.

3) Implicit casting to super-type (every object is an instance of class `Object`) compiles always. Causes exception at runtime if the list is empty.

4) The `add` method's signature for `List<? extends Animal> l2` is `l2.Add(? extends Animal)`. When we call `l2.Add(new Dog())` the compiler can't be sure that the type `?` is a super-type of `Dog` (since it doesn't know what `?` is, as we explicitely call the method using the `List` interface and not through an implementation of `List`), and therefore it must cause a compilation error.

*From comments:* "Note, though, that this issue has nothing to do with using an interface when referring to the container. The same compilation error would have occurred, when, say, ArrayList had been used in the declaration instead of lList." – Dirk

5) Assuming that the extra parenthesis is a mistake. Implicit casting to super-type compiles always. `Creature` is a super-type of anything the list `l2` can hold. Causes exception at runtime if the list is empty.

Comment: The reasoning in 1 and 4 is wrong, and so is the answer. 1 *will* compile, and 4 *will not*.

Comment: 1 reads fine now, though `Dog` does not need casting to `Animal` -- an instance of `Dog` *is* an `Animal`. 4 will not compile, regardless what you do. `List<? extends X>` means, that the list contains instances of some undefined subclass of `X`. There is nothing (except for casting the list) you can do to make the compiler accept the call to `add`.

Comment: Now 4 is correct. Note, though, that this issue has nothing to do with using an interface when referring to the container. The same compilation error would have occurred, when, say, ArrayList had been used in the declaration instead of lList.

Comment: @Snicolas: `List<? extends Animal>` could be instantiated as `*List<Animal>`, `*List<Dog>`, or as a list of any derived type thereof.